# Calling JavaScript function from C using JavaScriptCore

Tags: javascript, c, javascriptcore

I've written a function in JavaScript in an external JavaScript file sample.js . For example:

```
function getNum()
{
    return 123;
}
```

Is it possible to call getNum function from C using JavaScriptCore? If so, how?

I was able to call a C function "HelloCallback" from a JavaScript function using these steps :

```
JSObjectRef globalObject = JSContextGetGlobalObject(global_context);
JSStringRef helloFunctionName = JSStringCreateWithUTF8CString("hello");
// make function object
JSObjectRef functionObject = JSObjectMakeFunctionWithCallback( 
                      global_context, helloFunctionName, &HelloCallback);

// set it as proprty of global object

JSObjectSetProperty(global_context,globalObject,
        helloFunctionName,functionObject,kJSPropertyAttributeNone, NULL );

 // make javascript(using sample.js file)
 JSStringRef statement = JSStringCreateWithUTF8CString("/home/amit/Desktop/sampleWebkitgtkExample/sample.js");

// evaluate it
JSEvaluateScript( global_context,statement,NULL,NULL,1, NULL );
```

C function "HelloCallback" is defined in the C file as follows :

```
JSValueRef HelloCallback( JSContextRef ctx             
                    , JSObjectRef function         
                    , JSObjectRef thisObject       
                    , size_t argumentCount         
                    , const JSValueRef arguments[] 
                    , JSValueRef* exception)       {
// here do the C++ stuff
printf("\nHello from C function\n");

return JSValueMakeUndefined(ctx);}
```

sample.js file contains following sample code :

```
function getnum()
{
    return 123;
}
hello(); // calling C function
```

So If I want to call getnum() function from C, then how can we do in the similar way?

I did like this :

```
JSStringRef statement = JSStringCreateWithUTF8CString("/home/amit/Desktop/sampleWebkitgtkExample/sample.js");
JSEvaluateScript( global_context,statement,NULL,NULL,1, NULL );
JSStringRef script1 = JSStringCreateWithUTF8CString("getnum()");
JSValueRef x = JSEvaluateScript(global_context, script1, NULL, NULL, 0,  NULL);
printf("\n value = %d \n",x);
```

But I am not getting the returned value. Am I going wrong somewhere?

I did like this and now I am able to call the getnum function and get the returned value :

```
char* scriptUTF8 = createStringWithContentsOfFile("/home/amit/Desktop/sampleWebkitgtkExample/sample.js");
JSStringRef script = JSStringCreateWithUTF8CString(scriptUTF8);
JSValueRef  result = JSEvaluateScript(global_context, script, NULL, NULL, 1, &exception);
if (JSValueIsUndefined(global_context, result))
     printf("PASS: Test script executed successfully.\n");
else {
         printf("FAIL: Test script returned unexcpected value:\n");
         JSStringRef exceptionIString = JSValueToStringCopy(global_context, 
                                                 exception, NULL);           
         JSStringRelease(exceptionIString);
      }

JSStringRef script1 = JSStringCreateWithUTF8CString("getnum()");
JSValueRef x = JSEvaluateScript(global_context, script1, NULL, NULL, 1,  NULL);
printf("\nvalue = %f \n",JSValueToNumber(global_context,x,NULL));
```

createStringWithContentsOfFile function is defined as follows :

```
static char* createStringWithContentsOfFile(const char* fileName)
    {
        char* buffer;       
        size_t buffer_size = 0;
        size_t buffer_capacity = 1024;
        buffer = (char*)malloc(buffer_capacity);        
        FILE* f = fopen(fileName, "r");
        if (!f) {
                     fprintf(stderr, "Could not open file: %s\n", fileName);
                     return 0;
                }

        while (!feof(f) && !ferror(f)) {
        buffer_size += fread(buffer + buffer_size, 1, buffer_capacity - 
                                                           buffer_size, f);
        if (buffer_size == buffer_capacity) { // guarantees space for 
            trailing '\0'
            buffer_capacity *= 2;
            buffer = (char*)realloc(buffer, buffer_capacity);
            assert(buffer);
        }

        assert(buffer_size < buffer_capacity);
                  }
    fclose(f);
    buffer[buffer_size] = '\0';     
    return buffer;  }
```

Comment: Is [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/javascriptcore/jsvalue/1451648-call) what you're looking for?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I am writing code on linux for a Gtk+ application.

Comment: Ok, so you should create a context, evaluate your function declaration inside that context with a call to `JSEvaluateScript` and then again call `JSEvaluateScript` passing it `getNum()`. Documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/javascriptcore/jsbase_h), you just need to pretend it's C and not swift.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I tried with the steps(edited in the question). Please see if I am going wrong somewhere.

Comment: Try `printf("\n value = %f \n", JSValueToNumber(global_context, x, NULL))` (using `%f` in `printf` because javascript has no actual integer type, just generic numbers and `JSValueToNumber` returns a `double`)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca  Hello sir ! If I have to pass a C variable as an argument to the JavaScript function then How can we do that?

Comment: I suppose you mean to pass the content of the variable (like `int a = 5` and you want to pass 5 to the function). Just make a string out of it, like `sprintf(call, "getnum(%d)", a)`. Or if you have a string (like `char *a = "hello"`) use `sprintf(call' "getnum('%s')", a)`. Notice the single quotes around `%s`. In both cases `call` is a string you have previously allocated space for and will then evaluate.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Hello sir! I am able to pass an object from JavaScript function to a C++ function. But I am not able to pass a C++ object to JavaScript function. How can we do that. Please help!.

Comment: Hello again. I think this latest request is straying away from the original question enough as to require a different question altogether. Please create a new one. That way you'll also get inputs from other users that may never see this one.

Comment: ok. I will do the same.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I wrote a seperate question for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57003419/how-to-pass-c-object-to-javascript-function-using-javascriptcore
But did not get any answer yet. If you can suggest the steps I will be really thankful as I am unable to find it on internet. Thank you!